# SP 2016 with March CU stating Application with Search is not compliant

Tags: minrole

The minrole feature is supposedly supported, but is not reflecting such.

Comment: Which specific Service Instance is it calling out as non-compliant?

Comment: Hi Trevor. It doesn't specifically state.
The role is Application with Search, and is noted as not compliant.
I tried listing the services here, but there doesn't seem to be a clean way.

Comment: •`App Management Service`
•`Business Data Connectivity Service`
•`Central Administration`
•`Managed Metadata Web Service`
•`Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail`
•`Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service`
•`Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service`
•`PowerPoint Conversion Service`
•`Search Host Controller Service`
•`Search Query and Site Settings Service`
•`Secure Store Service`
•`SharePoint Server Search`
•`User Profile Service`
•`Word Automation Services`

Comment: The configuration of one or more servers in this farm doesn't match what is expected for its server role. You should correct the server configuration to avoid potential functionality or performance issues.
Failing Servers: PRODSPAPP

Comment: Could you please add screenshots of your problem? Could you please also add a screenshot of your Search-Topology? As SharePoint complains about search, i think the error is there. Search is unfortunately an application which must be configured manually via PowerShell

Comment: •[Server Role Incorrect Warning](http://i.imgur.com/b7FXW43.jpg)
•[Not Compliant Warning](http://i.imgur.com/ld2JoSS.jpg)
•[Search Service](http://i.imgur.com/gmYQlAm.jpg)
• The only notable thing is that the Global Search Center site does not yet exist. Not sure if it was supposed to create it automatically, but since the application exists, I think I can just create a new search site in that collection. Still, I don't think that should affect the Role compliance.

Comment: Okay, I think I found it, but do not know how to fix it. The "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" is the part that is out of compliance as it is on the WFE instead of the APP server. I clicked "fix" but it returned without error and without resolving. I assume if I try to unprovision it via PowerShell, that will be a fast-track way to screw the entire farm and all web applications already made. Is there a way via powershell to move this? Or can it be provisioned on the APP, and then unprovisioned on the WFE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] - Thanks to Trevor Seward

I had intentionally installed the Foundation Web Application on the WFE and not the APP, thinking it was correct since the APP should not serve pages, but apparently there are situations and reasons that it is needed on the APP server.

I followed https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/restart-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-web-application-service-stuck-at-stopping/comment-page-1/#comment-146 to provision the service and then the missing web applications.

The Provision() method can be invoked to only provision on the server that invoked it, instead of needing to use ProvisionGlobally().